# Server for Intranet with 14K visits per day

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, hardware, php5, intranet

I have an intranet with maximum 10-14k visits per day. It is developed with PHP, Rails and MySql. If I will moved from a shared server to a dedicated one, which server do you think I should need? I think a quad core, Xeon of equivalent, with 8GB RAM. Since I would like to use Varinsh and memcache, probably 12/16GB are better. I would like to use Apache, Mysql 5.5, PHP 5.3. The ORM of the PHP Framework (QCubed) has a big overhead on PHP. I had good results with Zend Server.

Comment: Core i7-920 12 GB 2*SATA for soft RAID is optimal for costs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless it's a seriously complex application I doubt you need half the resources you mention, modern day web application stacks can handle a surprisingly large amount of traffic - that said if you have kind of spec in mind then presumably you're aware of the costs and have come to terms with it. If that's the case then go ahead and buy what you want, I'm sure you'll have plenty-enough CPU and memory to handle that level of activity satisfactorily, of course you don't mention your disks, remember to include some form of RAID and a decent backup (we've had one or two questions this week regarding complete data loss so it's on all of our minds).

Comment: Agree, that sounds like overkill. One thing to check is your peak load tho, you might have 14k visits in a day, but 5k of them might happen between 9am & 10am ( when people start work ) check to see if their are usage patterns like this that might affect yor peak load.

Answer (score 2):

Before approaching towards hardware sellers, it's better estimate current load, collecting statistics of how many memory is used (and when), what is disk/CPU load, etc. Then you could (hopefully) extrapolate things.